# Using a SQL function to pad strings with spaces

Tags: sql, sql-server

Is it inefficient to use a user defined function to pad spaces?  I have a padding function that I'd more intuitive than using the built in REPLICATE function but I am afraid it is introducing inefficiency into the code.

The padding must be done in SQL.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: I assume you are left padding.  Right padding is trivial, because you can just cast the value to a `char()`.

Comment: Thanks. What we have is a lot of calls to user defined functions for right and left padding already written to do this and I'm wondering if it is worth replacing it with the suggestions above.

Answer (score 4):

You can use RIGHT or LEFT depending on the padding direction.
For example:

```
SELECT RIGHT('11111' + originalString, 5)
```

This will pad your string with on the left with 1s to make a 5 letters string. (I've used 1s instead of spaces so it will be easy to read. For spaces you can use the [SPACE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187950.aspx) function:

```
SELECT RIGHT(SPACE(5) + OriginlString, 5)
```

to pad to the right you can do this:

```
SELECT LEFT(OriginalString + SPACE(5), 5)
```

or simply convert to char as suggested by Gordon Linoff in the comments

Comment: Thanks.  What we have is a lot of calls to user defined functions for right and left padding already written to do this and I'm wondering if it is worth replacing it with the suggestions above.

Comment: You shold know better then anyone since you know you system best. It's probably possible to replace one udf call ant test performance, and then decide what to do.