# SQL query add zero if the value is a single digit

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have this part of a query:

```
        CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(dd, t.startdate,SYSDATETIME())) + '':'' + 
    CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(hh, t.startdate,SYSDATETIME()) % 24) + '':'' + 
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(mi, t.startdate,SYSDATETIME()) % 60) as Days
```

which translates to this:

[image]

What I want to do is, if there is a single value, for example in 15:9:40, such as 9, I want to put 0 in front of 9, to look something like 15:09:40.

Any idea how can I solve that within the query?

Comment: If the value is less than 10, add "0" in front of it.

Comment: [How to pad with leading/trailing chars in sql server](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866779/using-a-sql-function-to-pad-strings-with-spaces/29866897#29866897)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a built-in function in T-SQL called `REPLICATE`. You can use it like this:

```
REPLICATE('0', 2 - [length of your expression])
```

In you case the following should work:

```
REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(dd, t.startdate,SYSDATETIME())))) + 
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(dd, t.startdate,SYSDATETIME())) + '':'' +
REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(hh, t.startdate,SYSDATETIME()) % 24))) +
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(hh, t.startdate,SYSDATETIME()) % 24) + '':'' + 
REPLICATE('0', 2 - LEN(DATEDIFF(mi, t.startdate,SYSDATETIME()) % 60)) +
CONVERT(VARCHAR, DATEDIFF(mi, t.startdate,SYSDATETIME()) % 60) as Days
```

Comment: Can you please apply that function within my query, I'm not sure how/where to place that. Thx Kapol

Comment: @Laziale I edited my answer. I hope I got the parenthesis right.

Comment: @Laziale Take a look now.