# SQL Server trigger to update the same table

Tags: sql-server

I have a SQL server Table that has a `varchar` column that can save up to 4 characters

When we insert a value 963 into this column we have to add a leading "0" to this
 
for example:

- if I insert 23 the value should be saved as 0023
- if I insert 236 the value should be save as 0236
- if I insert 2369 the value should be saves as 2369

Can we add a AFTER trigger to this table, to check if the value inserted is less than 4 digits, and to update the same value in that column with Leading "0"s appended to that value

Will this affect the performance of the Trigger?
Is it a good practice to have a trigger to update the value in the same table?

Comment: I would recommend using a computed column instead of changing your data like this. What you have is a fixed width string instead of an int. This screams of poor design to me. Yes you could do this in a trigger but why do you need to have leading zeros like this?

Comment: these are kind of codes given to a specific set of users for example "0239" is a identification for a company named "ABC" and ""0023" is for a company named "XYZ" -  hope this helps answer your question ,

Comment: Not sure what specific users has to do with it. If you want these values for display or output that would be the right time to add your padding.

Comment: ... or format the data in the select statement ([see how to pad a string](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29866779/using-a-sql-function-to-pad-strings-with-spaces/29866897#29866897)) or better yet, in the presentation layer. since mathematically there is no meaning to leading zeros, application-wise there should also be no meaning to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can create a trigger and for one operation it almost did not affect the performance. 
Another way is to change the value when it use in select. e.g

```
select right('0000' + column, 4), ....
```